# Creating a new Xcode 4 project targeted to iPad only

Tags: ipad, xcode4

I'm attempting to create a new iPad project for an app I'm working on, prior to version 4 of Xcode you could select in the new project assistant what device family you are targeting.  In Xcode this appears to have been removed and all I can create is an iPhone project.  I can go to the project info and change the device to iPad, and Xcode converts it, but how do I just create an iPad project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your application template. Some (Tab Bar, Navigation) are tied to iPhone devices only, some such as Split View are tied to iPad devices only, while the "Window based" template allows you to pick iPhone, iPad, Universal.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem, I'm surprised though that you can't create a Navigation Based project for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Select the type under new project, and press next. Under device family you choose iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the target. Look at the screenshot:

[image]

The Devices dropdown allows you to select

- iPhone
- iPad
- Universal

Comment: Yes as I stated in my original post I'm aware you can convert a project to iPad after it has been created, but I want to know how to create a project from scratch specifically for iPad